# How to set different compiler path and includePath in c_cpp_properties.json on different devices for different projects in VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, intellisense

I have two projects, let's say they are proj1 and proj2. I wish to specify the corresponding compilerPath and includePath for VSCode intellisense. proj1 is compiled with nvcc, and proj2 with g++, so I can create .vscode folders and set c_cpp_properties.json in the two projects respectively. Everything works fine.

However, I now have two Windows PC, with one connected to local WSL and the other to a remote server. The path to g++ and the path of a third-party library needed in the includePath of proj2 are different on the two PCs.

So I set different environment variables in .bashrc on the two PCs:

```
export GCC_PATH = /path/to/gcc
export MY_LIB_PATH = /path/to/my/lib/
```

In c_cpp_properties.json, use the following settings:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${env:MY_LIB_PATH}/include"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "${env:GCC_PATH}/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "gnu23",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Then the following problems occured:

1. It seems that VSCode's intellisense doesn't recognize using environment variable in compilerPath at all. There are squiggles under "${env:GCC_PATH}/bin/g++".
2. Although there are no squiggles under "${env:MY_LIB_PATH}/include", intellisense still can't find the header that needs to be included in the .cpp file.

Also, since I have two different projects, setting up .vscode in the parent folder of the project folders might not be a convenient option either.

In view of the above description, I would like to ask, how to set up a useful VSCode intellisense environment for two projects on two PCs?

Comment: if cpp_properties support `${workspaceFolder}` but not `${env}` variable add a feature request in the C++ language extension

Comment: if you create an issue ticket, please add a link to it in your question post for posterity.

Comment: I posted an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/11186)